# How does one copy the state from a chaincode to an updated version of the chaincode?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

We are currently experimenting with Hyperledger's chaincode and wondering how we can gain access to the state held by an old version of a chaincode.

It is my understanding that the state created by a chaincode cannot be accessed by other chaincodes except through a query transaction. But, what happens when there is need to fix bugs/issues by releasing an updated version. How can we have full access to the state in the old chaincode?

Since direct access to the old chaincode state is not possible, does it mean we will have to build a mechanism within the chaincodes that allows for its state to be downloaded/copied/forked?

Querying old data from old chaincodes would be a nightmare when data is fragmented across many versions of a chaincode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any documentation to support this now, but Fabric v1.0 seems to have a variant of this feature - with a new switch called "**upgrade**". 
Have not tried it myself. So do not know whether the state can be made available across the different versions of the same chaincode. And the reason for the broken link is the difference in the Chaincode Id between two versions of the same chaincode. 
Take a look at this YouTube video, [Upgrade Chaincode](https://youtu.be/hlJmRKo8HXE). (Please note that this video uses the development mode, so Chaincode can be referred with the given name like mycc)

Also take a look at the fabric feature enhancement plan here for a mention of this feature[Fabric next, presentation](https://jira.hyperledger.org/secure/attachment/10056/FabricNext-Community.pdf)